# balls and bins problem: how to calculate the number of arrangements corresponding to a specific ball sequence before all bins are overflowed?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Considering throwing balls into $k$ bins where each bin can hold $m$ balls at most. Every time a ball is thrown into a bin and we get "$0$" if the bin is not overflowed; Otherwise, we get "$1$". This progress goes on and we get a sequence comprise of "$0$"s and "$1$"s, i.e., $00*010*010*011111**$. The very first prefix comprises of all "$0$"s since every bin is not overflowed, and the last suffix comprise of all "$1$"s as all bins are overflowed.

I just want to know what is the probability of a particular sequence before all bins are overflowed, i.e., the sequence before the last suffix comprising of all "$1$"s? The problem is hard for me, maybe because each sequence can correspond to more than one ball-and-bin arrangements.

Let us take an example. Say we have two bins:Bin $1$ and Bin $2$. Every bin can hold $2$ balls at most. Each time we throw a ball into a randomly picked bin, and when the bin is not overflowed (i.e., there are less than $2$ balls in the bin), we get "$0$"; otherwise we get "$1$". If we throw balls like this: $(1,2,4,∗)$, $(3,5,6,∗)$, we get sequence "$000101111∗$",where $(1,2,4,∗)$ denotes balls thrown into Bin $1$, and $(3,5,6,∗)$ denotes balls thrown into Bin $2$. Here the number $i$ in ( ) denotes the $i$th ball we throw. What is the probability that the sequence "$00010$" occurs (i.e., before all bins are overflowed)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify, what does "*" mean?

Comment: in the very first prefix, "$*$" means a number of "$0$"s, while in the last suffix, "$*$" means a number of "$1$"s; Otherwise, it could be "$0$" or "$1$".